# TINA simulation of TPS3701 Voltage Comparator output wrong

Tags: comparator

I am using TINA to design a voltage comparator, starting with the Typical Application of page 16 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3701.pdf):
[image: TPS3701 Typical Application]

When I run a transient analysis, the results are completely wrong, OUTA doesn't rise at 21.6V and OUTB falls at about 2V instead of 26.4V (and rises again around 1V!):

[image: circuit and transient analysis]

as compared to the datasheet output:

[image: datasheet results]

I'm completely stumped; is there a kind soul who could point out my blunder?

Comment: I would double check that R1 ends up being 2MegOhm not 2milliOhm

Comment: @sstobbe is correct!  Tina should show a value of 2MEG.

Comment: Its caught me before in LTSpice where even CAPITAL M still means milli, have to explicitly write 2MEG

Comment: @sstobbe Yes, milliohms rather than Megaohms hadn't even ocurred to me. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run a transient analysis, the results are completely wrong,
>   OUTA doesn't rise at 21.6V and OUTB falls at about 2V instead of 26.4V

OUTA and OUTB are open drain transistor outputs and rely on a pull-up resistor to some supply voltage to determine the maximum voltage outputted. Given that you chose a 3.3 volt pull-up voltage it's not surprising that you see voltages no greater than 3.3 volts. However, if it is a threshold problem then, as has been said in comments, 2m means 2 milli ohms. If in doubt write it as 2000k.

Answer (score 0):

For Tina learners like me, 2m means 2 milliohms, not 2Megaohms.

Fixing that produced the desired results:
[image]